# how to call a function with sting arguments

Tags: c++

I am facing an issue with a code I am working on. I want to write to a .txt file each time let's say a condition is fulfilled. However, when I run the simulation in which this specific code is attached no file is being created. I want your opinion concerning the function definition and how I do call it. Here is the definition of the function:

```
void writeToTxt(const std::string filename, int dir, double XPosTargetlane, double accelcurrent, double accelfollower, double accelaftproj, double acceltoldfollowerafterlanechange, double acceltargetcurrent, double acceltarget, int targetLane, double VelMobil, double currTime, int id_veh){
char buffer[500];
int n;
FILE* fMobil = fopen(filename.c_str(), "a");
if (fMobil != NULL){
    //Initialize output file
    n = sprintf(buffer, "\n  \ XPos \ accelc \ accelf \ accela \ accelto \ acceltar \ acceltarg \ dir \ tar \ Vel \  time \   Polfact=1.0 \ Δath=1.0 ");
    fputs(buffer, fMobil);

    //Store converted value to buffer and append to output file
    n = sprintf(buffer, "\n%.3f\t", XPosTargetlane);
    fputs(buffer, fMobil);

    n = sprintf(buffer, "%.3f\t", accelcurrent);
    fputs(buffer, fMobil);

    n = sprintf(buffer, "%.3f\t", accelfollower);
    fputs(buffer, fMobil);

    n = sprintf(buffer, "%.3f\t", accelaftproj);
    fputs(buffer, fMobil);

    n = sprintf(buffer, "%.3f\t", acceltoldfollowerafterlanechange);
    fputs(buffer, fMobil);

    n = sprintf(buffer, "%.3f\t", acceltargetcurrent);          //an*
    fputs(buffer, fMobil);

    n = sprintf(buffer, "%.3f\t", acceltarget);             //an
    fputs(buffer, fMobil);

    n = sprintf(buffer, "%.3d\t", dir);
    fputs(buffer, fMobil);

    n = sprintf(buffer, "%.3d\t", targetLane);
    fputs(buffer, fMobil);

    n = sprintf(buffer, "%.3f\t", VelMobil);
    fputs(buffer, fMobil);

    n = sprintf(buffer, "%.3f\t", currTime);
    fputs(buffer, fMobil);

    n = sprintf(buffer, "\n-----------------------------------------------------------------------------%d", id_veh);
    fputs(buffer, fMobil);

    fclose(fMobil);
}
```

}

And here is how I call it:

```
targetLane2 = numLane - 1;
    XPosTargetlane2 = vehicle->getPositionInTargetlane(vehicle->getPosition(0), targetLane2);
    vehicle->getUpDown(1, XPosTargetlane2, pVehUp, ShiftUp, pVehDw, ShiftDw);
    if ((simVehicleParticular *)vehicle->getRealLeader(temp) != NULL){
        accelcurrent2 = getIDMDeceleration((simVehicleParticular *)vehicle, (simVehicleParticular*)vehicle->getRealLeader(temp));    // ac
    }
    if ((simVehicleParticular *)vehicle->getRealFollower(temp) != NULL){
        accelfollower2 = getIDMDeceleration((simVehicleParticular *)vehicle->getRealFollower(temp), (simVehicleParticular *)vehicle);  //a0
    }
    if (pVehUp != NULL){
        accelaftproj2 = getIDMDeceleration((simVehicleParticular *)vehicle, (simVehicleParticular *)pVehUp);                  //ac*
    }
    if ((simVehicleParticular *)vehicle->getRealFollower(temp) != NULL){
        acceltoldfollowerafterlanechange2 = getIDMDeceleration((simVehicleParticular *)vehicle->getRealFollower(temp), (simVehicleParticular *)vehicle->getRealLeader(temp)); //a0*
    }
    if (pVehDw != NULL && pVehUp != NULL){
        acceltarget2 = getIDMDeceleration((simVehicleParticular*)pVehDw, (simVehicleParticular*)pVehUp);  //an
    }
    if (pVehDw != NULL){
        acceltargetcurrent2 = getIDMDeceleration((simVehicleParticular*)pVehDw, (simVehicleParticular*)vehicle);
    }


writeToTxt("Mobil114.txt", -1, XPosTargetlane2, accelcurrent2, accelfollower2, accelaftproj2, acceltoldfollowerafterlanechange2, acceltargetcurrent2, acceltarget2, targetLane2, VelMobil, currTime, id_veh);
```

Do you have any idea, why even if it builds correctly, it doesn't write a .txt file? .I haven't included any header because there is no point. The problem lies somewhere within either the function definition or when I call it.Thank you.

Comment: `if (fMobil != NULL)` -- did you check if it _is_ actually non-null?

Comment: Are you sure the file is written where you *expect* it to be written? How do you run your program? What is the current working directory of the program when it runs? What is your *expected* working directory?

Comment: A function accepting a ton of parameters is probably a badly designed function.

Comment: By the way, Why not pass the objects needed to the `writeToTxt` function, and it can extract the data it needs itself? And if you're programming C++, why use the C file handling instead of C++ streams?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would put some debugging statements to make sure the code is actually entering the `if` statement (as CompuChip suggested).

Second, if the code is being entered, I would make sure I check the working directory (as Joachim Pileborg suggested), but the file probably *is* being created, but might not be where you expect.